# Search for substring in Solr without wildcard?

Tags: php, string, search, solr

I'm extremely new to Solr so go easy on me :)

I have a field for arguments sake stores a product sku! If the sku in a document was 'SKU12345' - how would I return the document if the query '1234' was entered?

I have previously tried using solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory in the field type specific for the SKU but unfortunately this only works as a string prefix!

I want to try and avoid wild cards to keep performance optimal!

Thankssss :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are new to Solr and you are beginning to implement features like this, I would recommend to read thoroughly through the chapter [Understanding Analyzers, Tokenizers, and Filters](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Understanding+Analyzers,+Tokenizers,+and+Filters) of the reference guide. Since there are several ways to make your query match, but the best choice would depend on what you need.

Arun's suggestion is not bad, but the Ngrams alone are more geared to find general fractions of words. You would need this, if you want to do some sort of type-ahead or auto-completion. e.g. a User starts to type within an input field somewhere and you want to suggest previously made input that does match in fractions. If you try to make this match with Ngrams alone, your index may become quite large. Since you maybe required to index all permutations of the words to not miss the place where numbers/words start or end.

---

For your requirement I would tend to suggest [the WordDelimiterFilter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-WordDelimiterFilter) with `splitOnNumerics="1"`. So the input `SKU12345` would be indexed as follows

- SKU12345
- 12345
- SKU

So if a user searches for 12345 this would make a match.

---

If you want to match also fragments of that - like you said 1234 - I would then place a [N-GramFilter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-N-GramFilter) afterwards. Then you will need to play around with `minGramSize` and `maxGramSize`. You will want to keep the gap between the two values low. Since the higher the gap the bigger your index will become.

e.g.
* `minGramSize=4` and `maxGramSize=5`, gap of 1, few permutations
* `minGramSize=1` and `maxGramSize=5`, gap of 4, more permutations

This depend on how small the user input shall be allowed to make a match.

---

If only the input shall match only from the start and shall not hit fragments in the middle, I would suggest [the EdgeN-GramFilter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-EdgeN-GramFilter) as even better choice over the N-GramFilter. This will only generate fragments from the start of a word, not from the middle. This will lead to further reduction of the index size and better performance.

---

So if you want to make `2345` match `SKU12345` you need Ngram, if only input as `1234` shall match `SKU12345` EdgeNgram will do.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set side to "back" to generate the ngrams from right to left.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory

Comment: Thanks - I have tried this but the side="back" option is unsupported as of Solr 4 and above.

Comment: Why do you post the link as code and not as link? Just curios ... I cannot click it, copy n paste is somewhat inconvenient :)

Comment: Thanks @cheffe , i fixed and will keep that in mind in future. I think it was localhost ones that i had trouble posting , i will look around to do it right.